# Error: Bootstrap datetimepicker is not a function

Tags: html, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I am very new to html and bootstraping. I am trying to use datetimepicker function.

I know this question has been asked several times and I tried several different answers on the similar questions and still it throws the same error that **datetimepicker is not a function**. I appreciate if you could let e know what I am doing wrong. Following is my code:

```
     <div class="col-lg-4">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="datetimepicker1">Date:</label>
          <div class ='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1'> 
            <input type="text" class="form-control">
            <span class="input-group-addon">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
            </span>
          </div>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.10.3/moment.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.37/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
          $(function () {
            $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker();
          });
        </script>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Isn't it part of JQuery UI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Order of js file must as

1. jQuery and Moment.js
2. Bootstrap.js
3. Bootstrap datepicker.js

Try to use following code:

```
  <div class="col-lg-4">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="datetimepicker1">Date:</label>
          <div class ='input-group date' id='datetimepicker'>
            <input type="text" class="form-control">
            <span class="input-group-addon">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
            </span>
          </div>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.10.3/moment.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.37/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.7.14/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css">
        <script type="text/javascript">
          $(function () {
             $('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker();
          });
        </script>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: I tried this code, and now at least it can recognize the calendar icon when I move the mouse on it. But still doesn't show the calender when I click on it.

Comment: It gives the same error: Uncaught TypeError: $(...).datetimepicker is not a function

Comment: Thanks it's been resolved. Your answer was right. Since I am using cookiecutter in flask I had to put the css files in between  {% block css %} [.css] {% endblock %}.

Answer (score 0):

`datetimepicker()` needs to be initizialized on an `input` element inside of a div with the `position:relative` style rule.

[**JS Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/znLh9bp8/)

```
<form class="form-inline">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="dtp">Date: </label>
    <div style="position:relative">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="dtp">
      <script>
        $(function() {
          $('#dtp').datetimepicker();
        });
      </script>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but It still gives the same error.